# How would young earth creationist explain Omicron Variants?

Tags: young-earth-creation, covid-19

Young earth creationists believe that God created all the species 6000 years ago.

But what about Omicron Variant of corona virus?

Obviously it's a new thing.

What do they think about it?

Comment: Never forget the negative human influence that was responsible for the release of the virus that has affected 551.7 million people, killing 865,500 people worldwide (as at 30 June 2022).  Viral mutations are the norm, so you need to prove that these variants are "a new thing".  It would also be helpful if you would explain what you think this has to do with the creation.  Is Omicron a species?  Your question does not show any evidence of verifiable research, just claims.  Please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: So-called 'Young Earth Creationists' do not dispute intra-species, genetic, generational, diversification. What they dispute is the 'origin of (all) species' being due to prolonged mutation from a single source. The question misunderstands what YECs believe.

Comment: You yourself call it "*Omicron Variant*". A variant is a slight change to an existing species, so "obviously" it *isn't* a new species.

Comment: Some people believe the omicron variant was man-made AND that the novel coronavirus was man-made. So although easily explainable by YECs if they were naturally occurring, this is perhaps not the best example. :)

Answer (score 6):

> Obviously it's a new thing.

Since your question hinges on the validity of this statement, it should suffice to address this.

First off, YECs don't deny that humans are capable of meddling. There are all sorts of organisms that have been tinkered with by humans, and there have been claims made (which I won't go into here, as this is not the appropriate venue) that NCoV is one of those. God created all the species *that He created* ~6kya. But YEC doesn't claim (to my knowledge, anyway) that it's impossible that humans might create species *themselves*.

Second, YECs don't deny that species vary within certain bounds. That would be lunacy, as is plainly evident when you consider dog breeds, or any other animal that's been the subject of human selective breeding. (Dogs make a good "poster child", as they're well known and show *tremendous* variation within what everyone acknowledges is a single "species".) Our Creator designed each kind of organism with the potential to adapt to a wide variety of environments, and *that* is plainly evident. When it happens without the help of humans, this is sometimes called *natural selection*. (Be aware that terminology in this area can become very murky.)

What is **NOT** seen is dogs turning into cats, or into anything else that isn't a dog. (Note, however, that the "dog" kind includes wolves, coyotes, jackals, and others; in fact, so far as we can tell, created kinds, or [*baramins*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baramin), frequently — but not always — correspond to the [family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_(biology)) level. This diversity is more obvious in the feline kind, which ranges from [house cats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat) to [ligers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger). The ability of these animals to interbreed, even if only in the manner of a [ring species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species), is evidence of their common descent.) What is **NOT** seen is corona viruses changing into some other sort of virus. What **IS** seen is animals (and bacteria and viruses) reproducing "according to their kinds".

What materialists need to show, then, and what has never been observed, is an organism transmuting into a new *kind* of organism. In other words, your claim is false; there is nothing "obviously" new, and the assertion that it's new at all needs to be substantiated.

Comment: In scientific terms, small changes in a population are referred to as microevolution, and large changes (i.e. many small changes over a long period of time) that lead to new species are referred to as macroevolution.

Comment: @SamuelBradshaw I've only ever heard those terms used by creationists, but yeah, those are the terms they'd use to describe what's going on with the coronavirus variants.

Comment: @nick012000, well, let me introduce you to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution), which not only uses them, but even has [separate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroevolution) [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microevolution) on both, and is most certainly *not* a Creationist source. That said, "be aware that terminology in this area can become very murky"; getting people, especially on different sides of the debate (but also even on the *same* side!) to agree to the meaning of terms can be... adventurous.

Comment: So basically YEC believe in micro evolution but not macro evolution. The catch is, corona viruses are substantially different. That looks macro enough for me.

Comment: @obfuscated, substantially different *how*? This is an unsubstantiated claim. *Coronaviruses* certainly existed before 2019-nCoV. In order to claim support for "macroevolution", it is necessary to *show* that 2019-nCoV a) differs substantially from prior coronaviruses, and that, if such differences exist, b) they are not explained by b₁) horizontal gene transfer or b₂) human meddling. Have you done that? Has anyone? If not, your basis for denying — in effect — God's Word, is philosophical, not scientific / evidential.

Comment: I could imagine one could roughly map the [Viral classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_classification) of either family or subfamily to created kinds. As the answer says, family mostly fits, but not [always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominidae). In this case that would be Coronaviridae or [Orthocoronavirinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus). We've known about the latter since the 1920s. It's a rough mapping, because the field of biology is somewhat inconsistent with Creationism. But I guess that fits this answer? ie If poodle = wolf, then SARS-CoV = SARS = MERS.